# Is there a special template or syntax for null values in ListView?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a ListView:

```
myListView.ItemsSource = GetSomeData();
```

If in one of items in `GetSomeData()` one of the fields happens to be null, how can I display it on GUI as something like `"[Value isn't known]"` without having to check for being null in the "cs" file? Is there a special template for null values?

Comment: Create a custom converter class and use it while binding and use `Value="{x:NULL}"` in XAML

Comment: You might also like to view [A Comparable DataTrigger](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mikehillberg/archive/2008/09/30/comparabledatatrigger.aspx) which is not the answer but would give you glimpse to handle nulls

Comment: @MohitShrivastava, how exactly?

Answer (score 2):

You can create two DataTemplates: one for items that are present and one for `null`s. You can then use a [DataTemplateSelector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector(v=vs.110).aspx) to determine which template should be used for which item, such as below (adjust template keys to the keys you use):

```
public class MyTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        FrameworkElement element = (FrameworkElement)container;
        if (item == null)
            return (DataTemplate)element.FindResource("NullTemplate");
        else
            return (DataTemplate)element.FindResource("ItemTemplate");
    }
}
```

To use this on your ListView, simply add

```
myListView.ItemTemplateSelector = new MyTemplateSelector();
```

---

Above is the approach I recommend, but if you really insist on doing this purely in XAML, you can try the below approach:

```
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}">
            <ContentPresenter.Style>
                <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
                    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource ItemTemplate}" />
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding}" Value="{x:Null}">
                            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource NullTemplate}" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </ContentPresenter.Style>
        </ContentPresenter>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

What I did here is add another ContentPresenter within the ItemTemplate, and use a trigger on the bound value to determine which actual template should be used.

Comment: without having to check for being null in the "cs" file

Comment: @jawanam see edit for an alternative, pure XAML approach

Comment: will it work automatically for any Null value in any column?

Comment: @jawanam a ListView does not have columns; this shows the NullTemplate for a row where the value in the ItemsSource collection is null. You can of course have columns within your ItemTemplate, but you have to handle any potential null values there separately.